# How to correct GnuCash's incorrect claim of imbalanced imported multi-split transaction

Tags: gnucash

I'm in the process of importing an 886 line CSV file of multi-split transactions in GnuCash. I.e., each transaction includes the debit and credit line item. The problem I'm seeing is with every paycheck entry which is a split transaction composed of a gross salary (a credit to an income account) and ten debit items. When I import the CSV, every paycheck split entry shows up in red during the "Match Transactions" step. If I then continue with the import, an "Imbalance-USD" account is created with all eleven of these items. The resulting net balance is zero.

Here is an example of the CSV:

```
10/9/2014^Gross Salary^-2931.92^Income:Salary:Paycheck^
^Total Health - BCBS^32.90^Expenses:Medical:Health Insurance^
^Vision - Pre Tax^0.53^Expenses:Medical:Optical Insurance^
^Federal Payroll Taxes^682.21^Expenses:Taxes:Federal^
^FSA Total Health - BCBS^64.81^Liabilities:Loans:FSA 2014^
^State Payroll Taxes^107.85^Expenses:Taxes:State^
^Bought Vacation Buy^60.42^Liabilities:Loans:Vacation Buy^
^Dental Plan - Pre Tax^3.15^Expenses:Medical:Dental Insurance^
^Savings and Income Plan^175.92^Assets:Traditional IRA Investments:Fidelity SNL 401(k)^
^Deposit In X Account^700.00^Assets:Taxable Investments:TD Ameritrade X^
^Direct Deposit^1104.13^Assets:Cash:FCU Checking^
```

Each of these accounts have been created and are correctly matched during the "Match Import and GnuCash Accounts" step of the CSV import. Also, as you can see the amounts do balance.

I don't understand why the transaction shows up in red during "Match Transactions" step. The fact that it's red would suggest that the matching GnuCash accounts are not found. If I double-click on the red lines and select the proper account (exactly as it already appears in red), it turns to green. Why it doesn't see that already is what I don't understand and what I would like to fix.